# Calling Azure REST API from ASP.NET Web Api 2

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory

I have my front end developed as in AngularJS application. My back end is an ASP.NET Web API project. I want the users to be authenticated to my AngularJS application using Azure Active Directory for which I am using ADAL.js.

The authenticated users will then send some information to my back end Web API which in turn will call the Azure Management REST API to do work on the **user's** subscription. How can I achieve that? How will my Web API get the JWT token with the user's credentials to interact with the Azure Management REST API?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to call Azure AD on behalf of the authenticated user or would be you be OK with just using app key/secret for you application?

Comment: Hey @NikolaiSamteladze .. I know this is late. But still if you could tell me what you had in mind? I want to call Azure AD on behalf of the authenticated user.

Comment: Not sure about calling on behalf. I can only suggest looking into Microsoft sample here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof. Sorry